# Where are the javascript files from Magento 2.1.1?

Tags: magento2

I just have installed [Magento 2.x](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.33741025.1753232790.1472813916) in my computer, and when I try to run it the code can not find the javascript code.

In fact, it seems that all files inside en_US folder are missing. I only have the folder structure.

See the picture: [image]

Can someone tell me how should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please delete the contents inside the `static` folder from path `pub\static`.

After that run `php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy`

This should solve your problem

Comment: perfect! worked fine.